# check internet connectionreachability

Tags: objective-c, reachability

I check internet connection with Reachability in my App.
How can I check user connectivity contentiously, if his connection fails or change from wi-fi to 3G how can I be informed ?

right now here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

Reachability *myNetwork = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"google.com"];
NetworkStatus myStatus = [myNetwork currentReachabilityStatus];

switch (myStatus) {
    case NotReachable:
    { NSLog(@"There's no internet connection at all.");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"noInternet" sender: self];
    }
        break;

    case ReachableViaWWAN:
        NSLog(@"We have a 3G connection");
        break;

    case ReachableViaWiFi:
        NSLog(@"We have WiFi.");
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

how can I check interner connection before my app load, I tried this code in Appdelegate.m but I got an error because of  performSegueWithIdentifier methos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for checking any changes in user internet connection:

```
Reachability * reach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

reach.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       NSLog(@"Block Says Reachable") ;
    });
};

reach.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability * reachability)
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       NSLog(@"Block Says Unreachable");
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

*how can I check interner connection before my app load*

You **can** check the internet connection in appdelegate.  You just can't do anything to inform the user about it.  You need the window (and I believe the first view) before you can put up an alert.

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: that's what I tried,so the point is that I have no access to the view from appdelegate.
what I want to do is that internet connection check in every single seconds that app is running and if there is any changes happen, app shows a message to user.
how can I check it contentiously?

Comment: Contentiously? You mean continuously? --  Unfortunately, you *can't* show anything until the root view is displayed.  I would set a timer in the root view controller's viewDidAppear and check it however often you like after that. Be aware,though, that viewDidAppear can be called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

To check for internet connection you can use this:

```
- (BOOL)connected {
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

This returns a BOOL which you can use in a conditional to check for an internet connection.

**NOTE:** Be Sure to add the the proper frameworks and add the following at the top of your .m file:

```
#import "Reachability.h"
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
```

**UPDATE #1:**

Based on your comment it seems that you want to test for connectivity via a timer. The following code will check for internet every second. This is not recommended but this should accomplish what you are asking:

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/60.0)
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(checkInterWeb)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
```

Also you should create an ivar to the timer so you can invalidate it when you no longer need it like so:

```
if(timer) {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

Comment: hey
I have no problem with checking internet I already have it.
the problem is how can I check it contentiously?
if user connection fails how am I supposed to know?

Comment: Hmmm well you could use an NSTimer to check it every minute or so but do you really want that? Is it possible for you to only check when the user is about to do something that requires a network connection?

Comment: where can I set NSTimer that be valid in all my app?
there are many buttons and controlviews in the app and I cannot check internet connection in every single action, I need something like delegate that inform me if internet connection changes.
this is important for me because if internet connection fails then app will crash